# This is a question about lists in python. Can we concatenate two lists

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

```
 n=int(input("Enter number of rows: "))
 a=[]
 for i in range(n):
     a.append([])
     a[i].append(1)
     for j in range(1,i):
         a[i].append(a[i-1][j-1]+a[i-1][j])
     if(n!=0):
         a[i].append(1)
 for i in range(n):
     print("   "*(n-i),end=" ",sep=" ")
     for j in range(0,i+1):
         print('{0:6}'.format(a[i][j]),end=" ",sep=" ")
     print()
```

I’m trying to learn to print a pascal triangle, got struck at one line

```
a[i].append(a[i-1][j-1]+a[i-1][j])
```

is the above line what does the line do. can anyone explain a[i-1][j-1] does?

Comment: Can you show us the whole code instead of just one line

Comment: i have included a picture please have a look

Comment: It is bad to post code or data as pictures.  There is no way to copy and paste a picture into a code editor. So it will be much harder, and thus less likely, for someone to help. To get the most out of the site it is important to [ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), that includes creating a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example.

Comment: Please post the code instead of the picture

Comment: yes posted the code

Comment: You can debug the program using `pdb`. It will help you to get the flow and variable details on each line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that `a` is a list of list where `a[i]` is the i-th row of the Pascal's triangle.

`a[i][j]` stores the j-th element of the i-th row of the Pascal's triangle, it is an int.

They are just using the formula of [Pascal's triangle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pascal%27s_triangle).

```
a[i][j] = a[i-1][j-1] + a[i-1][j]
```